# MISSING DATA on data fetch

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am currently facing this issue that i never came accross.

When i run SQL query directly from PHPMyAdmin it shows total of 5 rows of 5 rows of data. However when i run this same query from a php script it shows only 2 rows out of 5.

its same sql code but not sure why its showing less data.

I have tried to restart mysql database but did not resolve the issue.

This is the SQL code.

```
 $today = date("Y-m-d");     
Select `pwd_orders_new`.*, SUM(item_price*qty) AS 'Total' From `pwd_orders_new` WHERE txn_id <> '' AND DATE(`adddate`) = '$today'  GROUP BY txn_id   ORDER BY `pwd_orders_new`.`id` DESC   LIMIT 0,20000
```

PHP CODE:

```
$_dbObj= new EPOS(DBHOST,DBNAME,DBPW,DBNAME);
$table = $_dbObj->get_orders_onList($id);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($table)){
$rows['orders'][] =$row;    
}
print_r(json_encode($rows));
```

Any help?

Comment: What is $id? Syntax wise, it's out of place if it's just a value.

Comment: Have you checked your server date and phpmyadmin date? Is both are the same?

Comment: Also `Select  pwd_orders_new.*` with `group by txn_id` isn't correct sql syntax

Comment: The code runs in php file all variables preset. when i echo the sql code and test on PHPAdmin it shows correct data.

Comment: $id variable is preset with a conditon. the syntax is correct. it works on phpmyadmin.

Comment: If you don't show the PHP code we can't tell you if it's correct. (How does your script execute the query, fetch and display the data)

Comment: the server date is corect. i test the date with this code and it shows current time date select NOW();

Comment: the php code worked correctly yesterday. I didnt touch anything. The script was working over 2 month without any issue. it just happend after server restart today.

Comment: Click "EDIT" below the question to update it with relevant information. It's easier for us to have all information in a single place.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a problem. You could replace `'$today'` by `CURDATE()`. Time could be the problem in some rare cases.

Comment: Unfortunetly CURDATE did not resolve the issue.

Comment: This happened few times to me. Most of the time I was checking a DB in phpMyAdmin but I connected to a different DB in the script